# Хочу получить URL Yahoo finance. Получаю ошибку

Tags: android, url, retrofit

Даю запрос и получаю вот такую ошибку:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL query string
>   "q=select
>   *%20from%20yahoo.finance.quote%20where%20symbol%20in%20({names})&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys"
>   must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query.
>   for method SharesAPI.getData

Мой интерфейс запроса:

```
public interface SharesAPI {
   @GET("yql?q=select *%20from%20yahoo.finance.quote%20where%20symbol%20in%20({names})&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys")
   Call<List<Shares>> getData(@Path("names") String stockIndexes);

   Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();
}
```

Мое активити и получение ответа:

```
public class InformationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     @BindView(R.id.tvAnswer) TextView tvAnswer;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_graph);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);



        final SharesAPI sharesAPI = SharesAPI.retrofit.create(SharesAPI.class);
        ShareService shareService = new ShareService();
        String[] indexs = new String[];
        indexs[0] = "AAPL";
        indexs[1] = "MCD";
        indexs[2] = "GOOG";
        indexs[3] = "AMZN";
        indexs[4] = "GPRO";
        final  Call<List<Shares>> call = sharesAPI.getData(shareService.joinShares(indexs));
        call.enqueue((new Callback<List<Shares>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Shares>> call, Response<List<Shares>> response) {
                // response.isSuccessfull() возвращает true если код ответа 2xx
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Shares shares = (Shares) response.body();
                    tvAnswer.setText(shares.getIndex());
                    tvAnswer.setText(shares.getName());
                    tvAnswer.setText(shares.getCost());
                    // Выводим посты по отдельности
                } else {
                    int statusCode = response.code();

                    // handle request errors yourself
                    ResponseBody errorBody = response.errorBody();
                    try {
                        tvAnswer.setText(errorBody.string());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Shares>> call, Throwable t) {
                tvAnswer.setText("Что-то пошло не так: ");
            }
        }));
    }
}
```

Класс, который мой массив переводит в стринги и добавляет кавычки с запятыми для запроса:

```
public class ShareService {

    private SharesAPI api;

    public Call<List<Shares>> getShares(String[] indexes) {
        return api.getData(joinShares(indexes));
    }

    public String joinShares(String[] indexes) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("\"");
        for (int i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
            if (i == indexes.length-1) {
                builder.append(indexes[i]);
                builder.append("\"");
            }
            else {
                builder.append(indexes[i]);
                builder.append("\",\"");
            }
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что нельзя динамические параметры в путь запроса засовывать. Путь должен быть отдельно, параметры отдельно.

```
public interface SharesAPI {
  @GET("yql)
  Call<List<Shares>> getData(@Query("q") String query, @Query("format") String format, @Query("diagnostics") boolean diagnostics, @Query("env") String env);
}
```

И вызывайте потом, формируя значение параметров динамически

```
String query = "select * from yahoo.finance.quote where symbol in (" + shareService.joinShares(indexs) + ")";
sharesAPI.getData(query, "json", true, "store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys");
```